# dynamically change checkbox background\foreground-color which is inside an itemtemplate inside gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I was having difficulties trying to change the background or foreground color dynamically behind code in c#. The checkbox is inside an itemtemplate, where the itemtemplate is inside a gridview. The gridview is bound with data, so there are many checkboxes, what i need to do is change the color of spesific checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write this following code inside RowDataBound event of GridView.Find that checkBox ,after that you can access that checkBox's properties

```
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("checkBox1");
                chk.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
           }
```

Comment: thank you, it worked perfectly: chk.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;